# How to Edit Records from database in Entity Framework 5.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi Dear All EF/ MVC4  Developers;

I have a problem with the editing of my controller, it shows me the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.EntityState' to
>   'System.Data.Entity.EntityState' . An explicit conversion exists(are
>   you missing a cast?)

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, Employee employee)
    {
        try
        {
            using(InformationContext context = new InformationContext())
            {
                context.Entry(employee).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which version of EF are you using? System.Data.Entity.EntityState is for EF6, System.Data.EntityState.Modified is for EF5.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  EF  6 or moving from EF 5 to EF 6, 
Dont forget to change System.Data.Entity.EntityState instead of System.Data.EntityState. 
This is an error that when your code is referencing Entity Framework 6 but your code is on Entity Framework 5.

[Click Here For More Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/upgradeef6.aspx)